# Show that $G_X\le{\rm Sym}(A)$ where $X\subseteq A$ and $G_X=\{g\in{\rm Sym}(A)\mid g(X) = X\}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Show that $G_X \le{\rm Sym}(A)$ where $X \subseteq A$ and $G_X =\{g \in{\rm Sym}(A)\mid g(X) = X\}$

I'm a bit confused with this question and how to approach it. First I believe I need to show $G_X \subseteq{\rm Sym}(A)$. Then, we know $g$ permutes the elements of $X$ in $X$ but the image of $X$ remains in $X$. When you restrict $g$ to $X$ I feel like you get a bijection (I'm not sure how to show this). I don't know how to show that is a subgroup (that $xy^{-1} \in G_X$) and how it relates to the symmetric group of $A$.

Also because I believe it is a bijection, does that mean that if the order of $A$ is equal to $n$, the order of $G_X$ is equal to $n! (|S_n| = n!)$?

I'm really confused

Comment: Use `$\{ x\}$` for $\{ x\}$.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t have to show that $G_X\subseteq\operatorname{Sym}(A)$: that fact is part of the definition of $G_X$. And there is no reason (or need) to assume that $A$ is finite.

Let $f,g\in G_X$. By definition $g\in\operatorname{Sym}(A)$, so $g$ is a bijection from $A$ to $A$ and therefore has an inverse $g^{-1}$ in $\operatorname{Sym}(A)$. Since $g\in G_X$, $g[X]=X$, so $g^{-1}[X]\supseteq X$. And $g$ is a bijection, so in fact $g^{-1}[X]=X$: otherwise there would be $x_0,x_1\in X$ and $a\in A\setminus X$ such that $g(x_0)=x_1=g(a)$, and $g$ would not be injective. Thus, $g^{-1}\in G_X$, and $f\big[g^{-1}[X]\big]=f[X]=X$, so $fg^{-1}\in G_X$.

Saying that $G_X$ is a subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(A)$ just amounts to saying that every permutation of $A$ that leaves the set $X$ setwise fixed has an inverse that leaves $X$ setwise fixed, and the composition of permutations of $A$ that leave $X$ setwise fixed is a permutation of $A$ that leaves $X$ setwise fixed.

**Added:** As Chris Custer points out below, I really ought to say explicitly that $G_X$ is clearly non-empty, since the identity map on $A$ is in $G_X$.

Comment: I have been touched up more than once for not showing, using the subgroup criterion, that the set in question is nonempty.  But of course we know the identity is in there.

Comment: As an additional question, suppose $A$ is finite however. I'm not sure what I'm missing here but I don't quite understand how $|A| = n$ is supposed to lead me to finding $|G_X|$.

Comment: @Johnny95: $|A|=n$ tells you that $|\operatorname{Sym}(A)|=n!$; to get $|G_X|$, you also need $|X|$. A permutation $\sigma$ of $A$ is in $G_X$ iff $\sigma[X]=X$, and since permutations are bijections, that’s the case iff $\sigma[A\setminus X]=A\setminus X$. Thus, such a permutation combines a permutation of $X$ with a permutation of $A\setminus X$. If $|X|=m$, how many permutations of $X$ are there? How many of $A\setminus X$? And how many permutations of $A$ are there that combine one of each?

Comment: Since $G_X$ maps $X$ to $X$, I think that there must be $m!$ ways to permute $X$, and so there must be $n-m!$ ways to permute $A\setminus X$ as $g$ is bijective by definition of being in $Sym(A)$. Does this mean $|G_X| = n-m! \cdot m! $. If so, why does what $g$ does to elements outside of $X$ matter in finding $|G_X|$

Comment: @Johnny95: Your calculation is correct, except that you need parentheses around $(n-m)$: $|G_X|=m!(n-m)!$. What $g$ does to elements of $A\setminus X$ matters because the elements of $G_X$ are permutations of $A$, not permutations of $X$; a given permutation of $X$ is the restriction to $X$ of $(n-m)!$ different permutations of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what $G_X$ is.  It is the set of things in $\operatorname{Sym}(A)$ which permute the elements of $X$ among themselves.  Isn't it obvious that if $g_1$ and $g_2$ permute the elements of $X$ among themselves, then so does $g_1g_2$?

Yes, if you restrict $g \in G_X$ to $X$, you get a bijection from $X$ to $X$.  This is also obvious, because $g$, being an element of $\operatorname{Sym}(A)$, is already a bijection from $A$ to $A$, and so its restriction to $X$ is a bijection from $X$ onto the image of $X$, which is again $X$.

No, the order of $G_X$ is usually not going to be $n!$.  Remember that $\operatorname{Sym}(A)$ is the group of bijections from $A$ to itself, and it has order $n!$.  Since $G_X$ is a subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(A)$, it will generally have fewer elements.  Maybe you are confused because you are thinking of $G_X$ as a subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$?  It is not, since the elements of $G_X$ are bijections from $A$ to $A$, not from $X$ to $X$.  However, there is a *surjective homomorphism*

$$G_X \rightarrow \operatorname{Sym}(X)$$

$$g \mapsto g|_X$$

where you "forget" what $g$ does to all the elements of $A$ which are not in $X$.

Comment: How does the fact there is a surjective homomorphism from $G_X \to Sym(X)$ and what $g$ does to the elements of $A$ not in $X$ lead me to finding the cardinality of $|G_X|$ when $G$ is finite and $|A| = n$

Comment: The cardinality of $G_X$ is going to be the cardinality of $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ times the cardinality of the kernel of $G_X \rightarrow \operatorname{Sym}(X)$.  Could you explain further where you are confused?

Comment: Why does what $g$ does to elements outside of $X$ matter in finding $|G_X|$

Comment: Think about if you have two elements $g_1, g_2$ of $G_X$ which permute the elements of $X$ in the exact same way.  It is still possible that $g_1 \neq g_2$, because they may not permute the elements of $A - X$ in the same way.